# Return a line of text from UITextView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield, multiline

I'm wondering if it's possible to retrieve a specific line of text from a multi-line UITextView in Objective-C (XCode 4 for iOS 5.1).  I'm talking about a textview that has multiple lines because the text has wrapped, **not** because there are line breaks.  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any help on this

Comment: We can get the complete string and then we can split the text and get the requires string

Comment: Thanks for your reply, krishna.  I think I understand. But how would I know where to split the text if I wanted to get the third line of the textfield?